# Optimize fill factor by move objects between areas

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I have a optimization problem which is about several small rectangles inside one outer rectangle. We have, let say, three outer rectangles which are in following order (similar to weeks).

Each rectangle have an area $X \times Y=Z$. The free available area is the area of outer rectangle, subtracted with the sum of all smaller rectangles. The inner rectangles has been added, and are continuously added by other users input. The optimization itself are One time shots.

Now I need to perform a optimization where the first of outer rectangle should be filled to max with move whole or parts of inner rectangles from the other outer rectangles.

Rule for optimization, The Y axis is static. The X axis is set, but adjustable. You can't move $X \times Y = 100 \times 30$ from second outer rectangle, if first outer rectangle only have $X=90, Y=30$ free. BUT you can of course move $90$ and leave $10$ left in the second box.

The first outer rectangle may very well have space for a $X=100, Y=25$ rectangle, but it isn't of help because the $Y$ is fixed. Though, there may be other inner rectangles in the following outer rectangles, which will fit in?

The output should be the content of each  outer rectangle (X Y of each inner rectangle)

Am I squeezed to a wall or is this solvable with normal math formulas?

Comment: I understand that something called "Knapsack" and "Stock Cutting Problem" is touching this. However i'm not really sure if it's fit to the very optimization *between* the rectangles.